# separate unit testing and E2E testing in npm build

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, puppeteer, ant-design-pro

I am using ant-design-pro in my project. For unit testing it's jest and for e2e testing it's puppeteer. To run tests we have npm run test:all which basically runs tests for all types of tests. Is there a way to separate these files to run tests separately like run only jest files(.test.js) or e2e files(.e2e.js)?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. One can pass file extension in such case in you package.json script.
For example npm run test .test.js
or npm run test .e2e.js